# Define default accessor of class instance

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to define a default accessor for an instance of my class?

I have a class:

```
class Foo
    def initialize(a, b)
        @a = a
        @b = b
    end
end
```

I want to create a new instance of this class:

```
foo = Foo.new(:a, :b)
# => #<Foo:0x00007f9e04c7b240 @a=:a, @b=:b>
```

Creating a new array returns a real value:

```
arr = Array.new(2, :bar)
# => [:bar, :bar]
```

How can I set a default accessor of my own class instance so that when I call `foo`, I get a real value instead of `#<Foo:0x00007f9e04c7b240 @a=:a, @b=:b>`?

Comment: What real value do you want `foo` to return?

Comment: I'm asking for general way of setting "default accessors".
I want to be able to return whatever I want e.g.:
`foo =>  "some string"` or `foo => [:a, :b]`

Comment: @Sepp please note that these "real values" are for low-level native objects and each of them has a literal syntax e.g. single or double quotes for strings, square brackets for arrays, curly braces for Hashes, numeric values, etc. Foo does not have a literal syntax and representing in this fashion could cause confusion. For example if `foo #=> [:a, :b]` then I would be inclined to believe that `foo` was an `Array` but clearly `foo` is not an `Array`. I would actually be inclined to say that the representation of `Foo` is actually more "real" since this is the default presentation of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see the output on the IRB console, all it's doing is calling `inspect` on the object. So, all you need to do is (like Array), define an `inspect` method for you custom object:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def inspect
    %["Real value" for Foo with #{@a} and #{@b}]
  end
end
foo = Foo.new(:a, :b) # => "Real value" for Foo with a and b
```

What you see by default, is just the implementation of `Object#inspect`, so you could if you really wanted to, just override that for all objects (that don't have a custom implementation):

```
class Object
  def inspect
    "Custom Inspection of #{self.class.name}"
  end
end

# Foo2 is the same as Foo just without the `inspect` method)
foo_2 = Foo2.new(:a, :b) # => Custom Inspection of Foo2
```

I'd avoid doing this for `Object#inspect` though, since people are used to and expect to see the default format and changing things might throw them off.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer!!

This is exactly what I was looking for!

I think this could be very useful if you want to create data type like structures.

Comment: Good answer, but the OP seems to have a misconception of "real value". You may wish to add a few words to address that; i.e., `"#<Foo:0x00007f9e04c7b240 @a=:a, @b=:b>"` and `"[1,2]"` both merely describe an instance of a class.